# How to handle an array containing both numeric and associative arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

The following code makes an AJAX call and then the returned string is parsed into a javascript object.

```js
function parseJSONArrayAndOutputToConsole(jsonString) {
  var result = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  console.log("ajax-response from fetchDataFromDatabase " + result[4]);
}

function fetchDataFromDatabase() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'Update.php',
    success: function(data) {
      //console.log("ajax-response from fetchDataFromDatabase " + data);
      parseJSONArrayAndOutputToConsole(data)

    },
    error: function(xhr, statusText, err) {
      console.log("ajax-error from fetchDataFromDatabase " + xhr.status);
    }
  })
}

setTimeout(function() {
  fetchDataFromDatabase();
}, 2000)
```

Now, the array returned from the AJAX call contains 1 string, 1 numeric value, 2 numeric arrays and finally one associative array.

When I try to output the associative array to my console, I get "[object Object]". 
The other elements work fine, only the associative array doesn't output its value(s). 
The contents of the associative array come from a call to the database inside the php script called by the AJAX call. 
The php script fetching the data for the associative array looks like this:

```js
//Lots of Code which doesn't matter for the issue at hand.
//The useCase I've been testing so far is where the user IS NOT
//an Admin.
if ($userRole == "admin") { //$testor  = 1;
  $result = $connection - > query("select id, name, vorname from benutzer order by name asc");
} else {
  //$testor =  0;
  $result = $connection - > query("
    SELECT benutzer.id, benutzer.name, benutzer.vorname FROM benutzer, benutzer_rollen WHERE benutzer.id = benutzer_rollen.benutzer AND benutzer_rollen.rolle != (
      select id from rolle where name = 'admin'
    ) ORDER BY benutzer.name ASC ");
  }
}
//The following else corresponds to an if which is not important here. 
// This else executes when the user is not logged in. 
//I didn't test the  
//behavior when the user is not logged in yet.
//Therefore, we can assume that any case I've tested so far, the data
//inside $result is fetched by the code inside the case where the user
//is logged in, but not an admin.
else {
  $result = $connection - > query("SELECT id, name, vorname FROM benutzer
    ORDER BY name ASC ");
  }
```

The associative array created this way seems to work, as it is later on used to set some HTML content. See here:

```js
echo "<option value='leer' selected disabled hidden>Benutzer auswählen </option>";
foreach($result as $row) {

  //second ajax call to create contents in selectInput
  echo "<option ";
  if (isset($_SESSION["loggedUser"])) {
    if ($row["id"] == $_SESSION["loggedUser"]) {
      echo "selected";
    }
  }
  echo " >";
  echo $row["name"].
  ", ".$row["vorname"];
  echo "</option>";
}
```

I'm having a very hard time to imagine how this associative array is embedded into my big return array from the ajax call, and how I can access its values directly, without using the foreach loop we can see in the code above.

Comment: When outputting object (or an array) to the console in JS, don't concatenate it with a string, as that will return "[object Object]", do the following console.log("ajax-response from fetchDataFromDatabase ", result[4]);
just add it as a second parameter to the log function, and that will output it correctly.

Comment: Just to confirm this, do you mean that I shall write

console.log("ajax-response from fetchDataFromDatabase ", result[4], console.log("ajax-response from fetchDataFromDatabase ", result[4]))

??

I don't think that I understood what exactly you want me to put as a second parameter to console.log?

Comment: Ahhh I got it :D Okay I'll see where this gets me ;)

Comment: console.log() can accept any number of parameters (arguments) and it will output any of them, trying to concatenate them as a string will just call .toString() function on that object, which usually doesn't output what you need to see :)

Comment: yeah :D 
However, now I'm getting this here into my console:

"Object { queryString: "\n
    SELECT benutzer.id, benutzer.name, benutzer.vorname \n FROM benutzer, benutzer_rollen \n WHERE benutzer.id = benutzer_rollen.benutzer\n AND benutzer_rollen.rolle != (\n
      select id from rolle where name = 'admin'\n
    ) \n  ORDER BY benutzer.name ASC \n ");
  }
"

can this really be the content, since I find it hard to imagine that this SQL command can become a functional, associative array? Oo

Ahh I see, it contains a lot more, its followed by "<prototype>: {...} where lot calls are

Comment: But how can I access one value of this array? Like for example, result[4]["name"] => returns "Robert".

Comment: The thing is, you didn't return the data, but the connection object itself from PHP (as I understood from your code), check this article https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp . The php connection object is pretty much useless on JavaScript side.

Comment: Yeah I also think that I didn't return the data I wanted ^^ 

What confuses me is that I'm returning the php array $result, which is already used in the LIVE build (same as here in my devbuild) and it obviously works. Since in the current live build, this $result is never returned to JS and processed inside the php script , does this mean that inside php one can handle a MySQL connection object just like any other (associative) php array? Or am I just doing something wrong when return the $result object, so that not the associative array is returned but instead this connection object?

Comment: Ahhhh I think I got a little bit further!
I must use -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM) (or whichever fetch I prefer) at the end of the MySQL statement to make it an array containing the values! Thx!

Comment: You can process it in php, check the link in my previous comment, that connection object can be traversed with a function like $result->fetch_assoc_array() in a while loop and assign it to a variable, but it does not change the result variable, which is still connection object, hope you understand what Im saying.